# Better way to create a Dataset?

Tags: dataset, associations

I'd like to create a Dataset from an array, where each column's heading becomes the key for all elements in that column.  I can accomplish this using nested Table commands, but was wondering if there is a more elegant way that directly leverages the syntax developed for Datasets. E.g., could this instead be accomplished using GroupBy?:

```
list = {{"date", "time", "volume"}, {a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}, {c1, 
   c2, c3}}
Table[<|Table[
   list[[1, i]] -> list[[n, i]], {i, 1, Length@list[[1]]}]|>, 
   {n, 2, Length@list}]
Dataset@%
```

[image]

Comment: I think you want something like `AssociationThread[{"date", "time", 
   "volume"} -> {{a1, a2, a2}, {b1, b2, b3}, {c1, c2, c3}}]`

Comment: @CarlLange  That doesn't quite work--try applying Dataset to your code.  But thanks for the suggestion to look at AssociationThread--I'll trying playing with it tomrrow.

Comment: Ah, it might be `Dataset@AssociationThread[{"date", "time", "volume"} -> {{{a1, a2, a2}}, {{b1, b2, b3}}, {{c1, c2, c3}}}]`? Sorry, I'm away from Mathematica at the minute :) (Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246088/dataset-from-association-of-lists-doesnt-work)

Comment: @CarlLange  That works, but only after an extra level is added to `Rest@list`, restructuring it from`{{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}, {c1, c2, c3}}`  to `{{{a1, a2, a3}}, {{b1, b2, b3}}, {{c1, c2, c3}}}`.  I could do that, but then I'm back to using Table.   I tried `Partition`, but it only adds an extra set of braces on the outside:  `Partition[Rest@list, 3]`=>`{{{a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}, {c1, c2, c3}}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This common data format, where the first row of data has column names, and the following rows are values, is easy to convert to a dataset with [`AssociationThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AssociationThread.html).

```
list = {{"date", "time", "volume"},
    {a1, a2, a3}, {b1, b2, b3}, {c1, c2, c3}};

ds = Dataset[AssociationThread[First@list, #] & /@ Rest@list]
```

Often, data from comma-separated values and other tabular file formats is arranged in the same way. For example, it's easy to import a CSV file to a dataset with the `HeaderLines` option. This avoids the need to convert an imported array.

```
ds = Import["file.csv", "Dataset", HeaderLines -> 1]
```

Related: [How to display properly Dataset with index column?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/197710/41569)

Answer (score 0):

a little bit late but:

```
Dataset[AssociationThread[list[[1]]->Transpose@list[[2 ;;]]]]//Transpose
```