# Creating a matrix

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I have a function as follows:

```
f[x_, t_] := x + t;
Table[{x, t, f[x, t]}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

When I write  `MatrixForm[%]`, I get

[image]

How to get a matrix as follows:

[image]

Comment: `data = Flatten[Table[{x, t, f[x, t]}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}], 1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f[x_, t_] := x + t;
z = Table[{x, t, f[x, t]}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}];
```

There are several different formatting options, including the following.  Note that the first two are presentation forms only; you can't do further operations on them.  You can see this for yourself by applying Transpose to each of the three.

```
z1 = Flatten[z, 1];
TableForm[z1, TableHeadings -> {None, {"x", "t", "f(x,t)"}}]
```

[image]

```
z2 = Join[{{"x", "t", "f(x,t)"}}, Flatten[z, 1]];
Grid[z2, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> All]
```

[image]

```
Dataset[AssociationThread[First@z2, #] & /@ Rest@z2]
```

(credit to @creidhne from [Better way to create a Dataset?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246108/better-way-to-create-a-dataset))

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the command `ArrayReshape`

```
ArrayReshape[
  Table[{x, t, f[x, t]}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}], {6, 3}] // MatrixForm
```

which gives

> [image: Blockquote]